# Wygwam: use apostrophes and proper quote marks

Tags: wygwam

Does anyone know if it's possible to get Wygwam to replace inch and foot marks (" and ') with apostrophes and proper, left and right curly quote marks? So **Don't** becomes **Don’t** and **"This"** becomes **“this”**? I think EE does this to titles, but Wygwam doesn't seem to... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your WYGWAM editor configuration setting, you need to add an advanced settings for “entities” and set it to no because WYGWAM encodes straight quotes as `&quot;` which prevents any typography processing from working correctly.

[image: entities setting]

Then use something like Typographee to parse the typography correctly (this is what I do): https://github.com/tjdraper/typographee

(There is an EE 2 branch on the GitHub repo as well so it’s not EE 3 only)